# preg_match for showing specific url within wordpress content

Tags: wordpress, preg-match

hi i has wordpress theme i want create the audio post format but when i call `the_content();` show me the audio player and the text content. but i want use `preg_match` php function in my post until show me only the url that end by `.mp3 or .m4a or .ogg` how can do this?

for information i want when i call `the_content();` function in mu audio post format don't show me any image or any text and any other urls. only i want show me the audio urls.

Comment: your question is not so clear to me - but it seems that you just need to change your theme files . That would depend on your theme and is very difficult to pinpoint here ( unless you will add more info )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

also i solved my problem by using this pattern below to show only the mp3,ogg,m4a,wav and wma formats from my wordpress post contents

```
$pattern = "/http:\/\/.*\/(.*)\.(mp3|m4a|ogg|wav|wma)/";
$subject = get_the_content();
preg_match_all ($pattern, $subject, $matches)
echo $matches[0];
```